# What are the requirements for a mobile app to do Geofencing?

Tags: android, geofencing, beacon

This works with Beacons and BLE (BlueTooth Low Energy), which of course requires Bluetooth to be on. Why does it also require location service to be on?  Can I physically turn off location, and still push notifications just using the BLE range ?

I also want to employ Geofencing.  Can I do this without writing an entire new app?

Comment: It's better to seperate different qustions from the same thread. You can aways make two threads.

Comment: Corrected grammar; tightened wording

Answer (score 0):

**As of Android 6.0, Bluetooth LE scanning is blocked** by the operating system **unless Location permission has been granted** by the user to an app, **and location services are turned on** in settings

**This is a privacy policy restriction** imposed by Android.  As you note, **there is no technical reason** this restriction must exist.  (Indeed, prior to Android 6, no such restriction exists.)  The theory is that because Bluetooth signals may be used to infer location, location security settings should apply to Bluetooth as well.

For geofencing, there is no custom behavior you can invoke without an app, other than what other apps already installed on the phone may do.